# Custom of not eating by other people on Pesach

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover, stringency-chumrah, hachnasat-orchim-guests

There is a custom that many have to not eat by other peoples houses on Pesach. Seemingly it's even if they have the same chumras or perhaps even *more* chumras (what I've learned over time is not necessarily does someone have "more" chumras, could just be different chumras.)

My question is is such a custom mentioned or brought down any where in Seforim? Is this a relatively "new" custom? How old si it? 
I suppose it's a relatively "new" thing since perhaps eating by other peoples homes in general might be a new thing.

Comment: Re "eating by other peoples homes in general might be a new thing", note that eating at others' houses is mentioned in _parashas Vayera_. +1, though.

Comment: @msh210 I was considering the fact that let's say 300 years ago (or put any amount of time here) people probably ate at home or with their family and not "stam" going to "friends" houses. People probably only had enough food for themselves.

Comment: @msh210, Yehoshua, "Kol Ditzrich Yeisei Veyifsach."

Comment: @SethJ People that don't have are usually not so makpid...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know. But *Rav El'azar Meir* Teitz [provided some data points](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol07/v07n018.shtml#03) (but the hyperlinks are mine):

> The comment was made that there is "a minhag amoung many chassidim to not eat anywhere except in their own house."
>
> This… was not restricted to chassidim; it was apparently the norm in [Lita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_Jews) as well. [My father z"l](http://www.nytimes.com/1995/12/29/nyregion/rabbi-pinchas-m-teitz-87-founder-of-schools.html) taught me to take nothing in another house on Pesach, and indicated that it was the accepted practice. Ylch"t, [HaRav Michel Feinstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Feinstein) told us of the time [Reb Chaim Brisker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Soloveitchik) visited [the Chofetz Chaim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisrael_Meir_Kagan) on Chol Hamoed Pesach, and the CC did not offer a cup of tea, so as not to embarrass RCB by making him refuse.